# ndarray::Array is not able to handle an arbitrary dimension

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I have a struct with an array

```rust
struct Model<const D: usize> {
  b: f64,
  j: f64,
  arr: Array<f64, Dim<[Ix, D]>,
}
```

And I noticed that I cannot access the value in arr via [usize; D], e.g.

```rust
impl<const D: usize> for Model<D> {
  fn sum(&self) -> f64 {
    // ...
    let mut cursor = [0; D];
    sum += arr[[cursor]]; // fail with error 
  }
}
```

because cursor is not implementing corresponding traits:

the trait bound `[i32; D]: NdIndex<ndarray::Dim<[usize; D]>>` is not satisfied

I would expect for an arbitrary `D > 0` ndarray should be able to handle it. Yet it is not possible. I am wondering if there is a workaround for this kind of isssue.

Comment: Did you try `let mut cursor = [0 as usize; D]`? `i32` is not `usize`, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately no, the error is "the trait `NdIndex<ndarray::Dim<[usize; D]>>` is not implemented for `[usize; D]`"

Comment: `NdIndex` [is only implemented](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/trait.NdIndex.html) up to `[usize; 6]`, but it's also implemented for `[usize]` slices, so `arr[&cursor]` might work.

Comment: @Thomas -- unfortunately not. Error is "required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<&[usize]>` for `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; D]>>`", while I am using `model[&s[..]]` where `s = [0 as usize; D]`

Comment: I tried your code but it gives several other compilation errors. After fixing those with _guesses_ at what your _actual_ code looked like, I got a different error than what you posted: `cannot index into a value of type ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; D]>>`. So please provide a minimal, self-contained, compilable example that demonstrates the error you're getting.